# How to use showDialog() method to changed dialog's title?

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I am using `showDialog()` to show a `DatePickerDialog`. I want to change or remove the dialog's title.

I tried adding these code

```
dlg = new DatePickerDialog(this, dsl, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
dlg.init(mYear, mMonth, mDay, new onDateChanedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue,
            int newValue) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

But the Eclipse shown

```
The method init(int, int, int, new onDateChanedListener(){}) is undefined
```

Then I tried to

```
extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnDateChangedListener
```

I set to log the date

```
@Override
public void onDateChanged(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
        int dayOfMonth) {
    Log.i("info", year + "/" + monthOfYear + "/" + dayOfMonth);
}
```

But I didn't get the log info.
Does anyone know how to use `showDialog()` to change or set the title?

Answer (score 0):

the method ShowDialog() was deprecated in API 13 so don't use it.
u can simply use it as below

```
DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(
MainActivity.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
        dayOfMonth+"-"+(++monthOfYear)+"-"+year,
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
},2014, 1, 24); 

dp.setTitle("My title");
dp.show();
```

Comment: sorry,@kevz. I have write hide year field in protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {}. If you set dp.setTitle. When the dialog turn on , user in onChanged date. The title will show date, not hide year. So I need find how to write set title in unchanged about use ShowDialog(). Thanks.

Comment: didn't got wt u want exactly? plz write in steps wt u seek to achieve?

Comment: I haven't find nice solution. So I changed method to hide the dialog title. If you have better solution, we can discuss

Answer (score 0):

I find other changed method.
I removed the title when the date picker turn on.
we just set " (dialog object).setTitle(null); 
We can hide the title.